# Как в скрипте вывести сообщение?

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть скрипт для СУБД Firebird script.sql

```
OUTPUT c:\temp\debug.txt;
-- тут хочу вывести свое сообщение, как мне это сделать?
-- например: это таблица номер один
SELECT * FROM table1; -- замечательно выводит содержимое таблицы
OUTPUT;
```

Comment: `select 'Это таблица номер один' from rdb$database` или что за сообщение? Если это isql, то можно вызвать shell комманду(по крайней мере для linux) `SHELL echo "This is table number one";`

Comment: неужели нет ни какой команды типа Echo или Print ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отладки и логирования выполнения скрипт(а/ов) из программы,

команда OUTPUT не подходит, она подходит для утилит ISQL и IBExpert.

Для выше названных целей лучше всего использовать внешние таблицы.

```
create table ext_log
external file 'c:\log\log.txt'(
dt   char( 25) character set win1251,
msg  char(100) character set win1251,
crlf char(  2) character set win1251);

create trigger dt_crlf_ext_log for ext_log
active before insert
as
begin
  if (new.dt is null) then new.dt = cast(current_timestamp as char(24));
  new.crlf = ascii_char(13) || ascii_char(10);
end

insert into ext_log (msg) values ('привет мир!');
```

Comment: В СУБД Oracle, а вернее в их IDE Oracle SQL Developer есть dbms_output.put_line('привет мир!'). Почему в IBExpert такого нету?